# Stop attribute's href from changing page

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is this, I am using Ajax to load my pages and so I don't want the href to change the page when I click on a link, however if a user on my site wanted to copy a link to that page I still want it to function.  So I do not want to get rid of the href.  What are my options?

Current Code:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <a href="bar.html" id='click'>Click to change url to bar.html</a>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
  function change_my_url() {
   history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
  }
  var link = document.getElementById('click');
  link.addEventListener('click', change_my_url, false);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You have officially confused me... you DON'T want the active URL to change, but you want to load a new site?

Comment: Did you try adding `return false;` to the `change_my_url()` function?

Comment: @AlejandroIván Yes, @ NicholasHazel Active URL to change while loading content with ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `event.preventDefault` in the click function for the `<a>` tag.

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.myDisabledLink');

for (var i=0; i<elems.length; ++i) {
  addClickFunc(elems[i], i);
}

function addClickFunc(elem, i) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(elem.href);
    //do whatever else you need to do.
  });
}
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/awIduqId/1/edit)**

The sample markup I used:

```
<a href="some/place" class="myDisabledLink">Click me!</a>
<a href="a/link" class="myDisabledLink">Click me!</a>
<a href="another/link" class="myDisabledLink">Click me!</a>
```

Comment: Sorry I should have added I have tried both of these, neither working. FF26

Comment: While using what you provided along with history.PushState the history.PushState no longer works

Comment: @user3196380 wait, what!? You said you wanted to use ajax to load the new page.

Comment: @user3196380 I think the issue is that you don't know how to use `history`. It's not that it stopped working, it's that it never worked. Your question title is "Stop attribute's href from changing page". I answered that. If you have a question about `history.PushState`, that should be a different question.

Comment: code works properly when using href="#" however that does not give the correct link when trying to "copy link location"

Comment: For reference, see the console.log in this demo: http://jsbin.com/awIduqId/4/edit When you click on a link, the page's href attribute is changed to the href of the link, just as it should according to the docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: @user3196380 if this doesn't prove my point, nothing will: http://jsbin.com/awIduqId/6/edit That is the exact code you just discussed, doing exactly the same thing as my previous demo.